# Interop - Whether to call native from managed or vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c++-cli, interop

I have been reading about native managed interops using C++ CLI, and I understand that interops are possible both ways - you can either call a managed assembly from native code, or a native (mixed) assembly from managed.

My question is - are there any guidelines/rules of thumb to chose a direction for interop, i.e. to decide whether to call native from managed or vice versa. Or it makes no difference which way I interop?

In my case, I have native code that does a lot of data processing, and real time communication. This has to be made to work with a neat looking WPF GUI. I could either have my native code call WPF functionality, or have a neat C# WPF front end call into native backend. I also have a View that would have to hosted in WPF but its contents would need to be regularly updated from native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's typically easier in the long run to have your UI call into your "logic" code, which in this case, would mean a managed application which calls into the native code.

Both "layers" end up being the same as if you were doing the entire application in that technology, so neither becomes odd.  As soon as you start trying to create managed UI from within native code that isn't UI based, you end up having to jump through hoops to make things work as expected.

As such, I'd recommend making a WPF application, and just call into your data processing and communication as needed.